# When I use the document object to operate the dom in vue , an error will be reported, but using jquery to operate the dom will not

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

(I know vue is the node environment, not the browser environment,so using document is false),but using jquery to operate the dom will not.

When I use the document object to operate the dom in vue (vue is the node environment, not the browser environment), an error will be reported, but using jquery to operate the dom will not. Why? Does the implementation of jquery not use the document object?

Comment: Your question makes zero sense without code. `Vue is the node environment`???

Comment: Also [Vue2 is EOL](https://v2.vuejs.org/)

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: "_an error will be reported_"... Did it not seem prudent to include the error with your question?  Regardless, you can access the DOM with `document` interface no problem in Vue, although it's not a good idea because the Vue framework is meant to manage the DOM, not you.  For that reason, it's not a good practice to use jQuery with Vue either.  Maybe if you had included the full error details we would be able to better help understand your problem.